# Term for operations not required to satisfy axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, binary-operations

My understanding is that addition and multiplication are operations required to satisfy field axioms and that one may construct a field without defining the operations of subtraction and division. On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) Wikipedia page, subtraction and division are referred to as "inverse" operations, which I believe I understand in context. Is there a term other than "inverse" that may be used to characterize such operations not required to satisfy axioms that may be defined for a given algebraic structure?

Intuitively, I would guess at natural language terms such as "secondary operations," "subsequent operations," and "implicit operations," though I would like to know what, if any, terms are actually used or would be appropriate to use to refer to operations that aren't required for qualification as a given algebra but may nevertheless be defined for it.

Comment: Generally such operations are often called *derived operations*.  They are studied abstractly in algebraic structures via the notion of [clones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)). See also [extension by definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say I had a ring of matrices with addition and multiplication. There are loads of more complex operations we can define in terms of those starting ones. For example $[X,Y] = XY-YX$. In fact this definition makes sense for an arbitrary ring and what it means depends on what addition and multiplication mean. If I had to give a name for all such operations I would call them *derived operations*. But if you're only dealing with a few specific ones you should just give them names. The operation $[X,Y]$ is sometimes called the *commutator* or *Lie bracket* and it is derived from addition and multiplication.